# What is the relationship between constructivism and object oriented programming?

Tags: computer-science, mathematical-logic

I am exploring the topic of constructivism from discreet math, and think it is related to object oriented programming. Can anyone confirm or deny the two are related?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "constructivism"?  it's a fairly broad term.

Comment: Some of the history is discussed under [Was object oriented programming influenced by the mathematical category theory?](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/630/was-object-oriented-programming-influenced-by-the-mathematical-category-theory) Early developments in object oriented programming were influenced by the [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus), there are also parallels to [Martin-Löf's constructivist type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_type_theory).